# Change softkeyboard in Android - works in simulator only

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to invoke a specific keyboard in Android, one which has a "Done" button at the bottom:

```
    <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/PlayerName"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="33dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"  
    android:text="" 
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    />
```

This works fine on the simulator, displays it properly, but it does not work on the device i use for testing, an LG-P970.

Am I mimssing something in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IME options are specific to input methods. The emulator has the standard input method, but it is pretty common for manufacturers to implement their own input method that has the look and feel of their UI. That might be what you're seeing. Also, not all input methods will behave the same way. For instance a voice command input method might have no concept of an "actionDone". It might be better to avoid programming against an "ideal" input method.

Perhaps we could suggest a different way to do what you want to do?

Comment: The keyboard is triggered by tapping into a search box, and the user should have a simple "Done" (or Cancel button if you will) to make the keyboard disappear and the search box empty. - Currently the standard keyboard is a bit too cryptic for non geeks and I am catering to 2 different languages. So a "done" or "fin" in the button itself will make things obvious.

Comment: @LePierre There are other ways of making the input method disappear besides a "done" button. The back button or tapping on the screen should have the same effect. How is the standard keyboard to cryptic? If the user is using the LG-P970 then they will be familiar with that keyboard. Trying to change standard conventions will be most confusing to the user. I'm still confused about the context of what your button is doing because "done" and "cancel" seem like opposites to me.

Comment: I think I should have posed the q differently and I apologize: In my app the user gets to see a standard android keyboard. However, some users with e.g. a Samsung Galaxy by default have a different keyboard. And they should get to see their standard keyboard, not my default android one.